# Trigger android shutter from 3.5mm camera signal

Tags: remote, shutter-release, android

I have a project in which one of my devices sends a timed shutter release signal via 3.5mm out.  I would like to pick up this signal and trigger two Android phones

I've looked around and haven't found a solution. A few questions arise.

- is triggering the shutter possible on a USBC only phone as it was previously with 3.5mm headphones
- is triggering the shutter possible through a USBC dongle
- can I catch the camera shutter release signal and convert it into the expected android signal?
- is there a USBC native way to trigger the shutter?

Any info would be helpful, I'd rather not try if this isn't possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it have nothing to do with photography per se. Better ask here: https://android.stackexchange.com/